# How to set a namespace prefix programmatically with RmlMapper?

Tags: java, rdf, rml-rdf

When using [Carml](https://github.com/carml/carml), I can define a namespace prefix in the [RML](https://rml.io/specs/rml/) file with:

```
carml:declaresNamespace [
      carml:namespacePrefix "tei";
      carml:namespaceName "http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";
];
```

Reading the [RmlMapper](https://github.com/RMLio/rmlmapper-java) Github issues it seems that there is no equivalent (yet) in RmlMapper.

How to set a namespace prefix programmatically with RmlMapper?

**Note:**

In [XMLRecordFactory](https://github.com/RMLio/rmlmapper-java/blob/master/src/main/java/be/ugent/rml/records/XMLRecordFactory.java), we see:

```
// Extract and register existing source namespaces into the XPath compiler
SaxNamespaceResolver.registerNamespaces(compiler, document);
```

And indeed, if I change my source XML from:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="article_001">
```

to

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="article_001">
```

The namespace prefix is correctly defined for XPath. But I don't want to change all XML source files.